# ReferenceError: fblogin is not defined at new LoginController - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add a simple login via facebook but I'm having some trouble.

.js file:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    LoginController.$inject = ['$location', 'AuthenticationService', 'FlashService'];
    function LoginController($location, AuthenticationService, FlashService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.login = login;
        vm.fblogin = fblogin;
        (function initController() {
            // reset login status
            AuthenticationService.ClearCredentials();
        })();
        fblogin = function(){
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                });
                } else {
                console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            });
        }
        function login() {
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            AuthenticationService.Login(vm.username, vm.password, function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    AuthenticationService.SetCredentials(vm.username, vm.password);
                    $location.path('/');
                } else {
                    FlashService.Error(response.message);
                    vm.dataLoading = false;
                }
            });
        };

    }

})();
```

And the .html:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.login()" role="form">
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.username"/>
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.password" />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <button ng-click="vm.fblogin()">Facebook Login</button>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
            <a href="#/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

the only part that really matter in the html is this one:

```
<button ng-click="vm.fblogin()">Facebook Login</button>
```

And I'm getting this error:
ReferenceError: fblogin is not defined
    at new LoginController

Comment: I don't see the part `ng-controller="LoginController as vm"` are you sure the button is in the scope of this controller?

Comment: It is on another file. The problem is that I cannot reach fblogin, probably I'm being to noob but, I hope someone can tell me.

Comment: What if you create a variable `vm.test = "this is the test"` and then display it in template next to button `{{vm.test}}` to see if they are in the scope

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct APP id and the redirect url set in the app settings.

```
.config([
    'FacebookProvider',
    function(FacebookProvider) {
     var myAppId = '1367223633302978';     
     FacebookProvider.init(myAppId);     
    }
  ])
```

**[DEMO](https://github.com/sajeetharan/FBAngularApp)**